# ng grid dynamic display

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Please find the following [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uPB5jrrFOgCASRvEFm0k?p=preview). I am not able to show ng grid on button click. Is there anything wrong in the code?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.changeEntity = function () {
  $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
    $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
}
});
```

Comment: If I write the code out side of the method it works on page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to define your `gridOptions` in your controller onLoad itself, not on a function call. But you can load data on a function call,
in your case its button click.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };

$scope.changeEntity = function () {

  $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
 }
});
```

Note: in your **Plunker** js file name needs to be changed!!